# Possible logic or semantic error in CentOS7 vs RHEL7

Tags: centos, rhel, brace-expansion

I came across this problem a few weeks ago but I thought it was my system acting up. But after a couple of investigations, I believe this could be a bug. Or maybe I am wrong. When attempting to `echo` or `touch` multiple files on CentOS7 such as: `echo file{a..c}.txt` doing this on CentOS7 returns `file{a..c}.txt`
but performing the same command on RHEL7 returns: `filea.txt fileb.txt filec.txt`

Is anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: check shell & environment variables may explain syntax difference in results

Comment: Do you have the same minor revisions (say 7.0 vs 7.4), same user (say root vs non-root, and subsequently same shell), same host virtualization (say inside docker container vs physical host). If absolutely everything is the same, then it's at least strange because CentOS builds from the same source packages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would see this behavior if your shell on the CentOS system was `dash`, which does not expand brace ranges like that:

```
$ for shell in bash dash ksh
> do
> echo in $shell:
> $shell -c 'echo file{a..c}.txt'
> done
in bash:
filea.txt fileb.txt filec.txt
in dash:
file{a..c}.txt
in ksh:
filea.txt fileb.txt filec.txt
```

---

[From the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426185/possible-logic-or-semantic-error-in-centos7-vs-rhel7/426215#comment768685_426246) you're using zsh on the CentOS system. I can reproduce the behavior by setting the `ignorebraces` shell option:

```
$ set -o|grep ignorebraces
ignorebraces          off
$ echo {1..3}
1 2 3
$ set -o ignorebraces
$ echo {1..3}
{1..3}
$ set +o ignorebraces
$ echo {1..3}
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what shell you are using on the various systems.

Brace expansion is an extension to the POSIX standard for the shell and not every shell implements it.  Those who do may do it in different ways.

The `dash` shell does not implement brace expansion:

```
$ echo {0..9}
{0..9}
$ echo {1,2,3}
{1,2,3}
```

The `pdksh` shell (as found on OpenBSD) implements brace expansion, but not for ranges:

```
$ echo {0..9}
{0..9}
$ echo {1,2,3}
1 2 3
```

The `bash`, `zsh`, and `ksh93` shell implements ranges (both numerical and alphabetic)

```
$ echo {0..9}
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
$ echo {1,2,3}
1 2 3
```

Comment: I am actually using bash on rhel7 and zsh on Centos7 could that be the reason why the brace expansion works on rhel and not Centos ?

Comment: @christianx Hmm... I explicitly tested with zsh without problems. I'm not at a computer now (on the phone). What version of zsh are you using? It ought to support brace expansion out of the box.

Comment: zsh --version returns: zsh 5.0.2

Comment: @christianx I'm on 5.4.2 and I can't reproduce what you're seeing on CentOS on my machine with this version of `zsh`. I also do not have access to an older version to test with. I can't find anything relevant in the release notes for the releases between your and my version of the shell either...

Comment: @christianx is it possible that you've disabled brace expansion in zsh? `set -o ignorebraces` would do it.